# Building plain chain spec yields raw output

Tags: chainspec, command

The command `substrate build-spec > plain-chain-spec.json` used to generate a human readable version of the chain spec in json. To create the more stable machine friendly version of that chain spec one must call: `substrate build-spec --raw > raw-chain-spec.json`. But now that I'm testing a node built on top of `Polkadot 0.9.42`, I'm observing that the output of the former command is also raw! How can the plain version is producible then?

Comment: When I specified the chain in the build-spec command, this time around the result was indeed plain!

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issue with the command you are using to generate the `plain spec file`, you can follow the steps mentioned in this tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/add-trusted-nodes/#create-a-custom-chain-specification, also the command to generate the plain spec file is as follows:

```
./target/release/node-template build-spec --disable-default-bootnode --chain local > customSpec.json
```